# Conditionally adding an Option to a List

Tags: scala

If I want to add the value of an `Option` (should it have one) to a List, is there a better way than:

```
val x = Some(42)
val xs = List(1,2,3)
val xs2 = x match {
  case None => xs
  case Some(x2) => x :: xs
}
```

I know I can use the `++` operator on `Iterable` like this:

```
val xs2 = (x ++ xs).toList
```

But does that explicit conversion back to `List` cause the entire list to be scanned and copied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `++:` to return a `List` instead of an `Iterable` (skipping the `.toList` call) :

```
scala> val x = Some(42)
x: Some[Int] = Some(42)

scala> val xs = List(1,2,3)
xs: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> x ++: xs
res4: List[Int] = List(42, 1, 2, 3)

scala> val x = None
x: None.type = None

scala> x ++: xs
res5: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: From Scala 2.13, `++:` is deprecated, you can just use `++` for collections of type Iterable.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
val x: Option[Int] = Some(42)
val xs = List(1,2,3)
val xs2 = xs ++ (x match {
  case Some(value) => List(value)
  case None => List()
})
```

Note that I had to tell Scala that `x` is an `Option[Int]` so that it wouldn't assume it was a `Some[Int]` and complain about the matching.